# How to install MySQLdb package? (ImportError: No module named setuptools)

Tags: python, mysql, installation

I am trying to install MySQLdb package. I found the source code [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/).

I did the following:

```
gunzip MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.tar.gz
tar xvf MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.tar
cd MySQL-python-1.2.3c1
python setup.py build
```

As the result I got the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in ?
    from setuptools import setup, Extension
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Does anybody knows how to solve this problem?
By the way, if I am able to do the described step, I will need to do the following:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

And I have no system-administrator-rights. Do I still have a chance to install MySQLdb?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to get setuptools. See: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If MySQLdb's now distributed in a way that requires `setuptools`, your choices are either to download the latter (e.g. from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)) or refactor MySQLdb's setup.py to bypass `setuptools` (maybe just importing `setup` and `Extension` from plain `distutils` instead might work, but you may also need to edit some of the `setup_*.py` files in the same directory).

Depending on how your site's Python installation is configured, installing extensions for your own individual use without requiring sysadm rights may be hard, but it's never truly impossible if you have shell access. You'll need to tweak your Python's sys.path to start with a directory of your own that's your personal equivalent of the system-wide site pacages directory, e.g. by setting `PYTHONPATH` persistently in your own environment, and then manually place in said personal directory what normal installs would normally place in site-packages (and/or subdirectories thereof).

Answer (score 28):

After trying many suggestions, simply using `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb` worked for me.

More info: 
[Getting "Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb" - have tried previously posted solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952187/getting-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb-have-tried-pre)

Answer (score 11):

I resolved this issue on centos5.4 by running the following command to install setuptools

yum install python-setuptools

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

This was sort of tricky for me too, I did the following which worked pretty well.

- Download the appropriate Python .egg for setuptools (ie, for Python 2.6, you can get it [here](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg#md5=ca37b1ff16fa2ede6e19383e7b59245a). Grab the correct one from the PyPI site [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).)
- `chmod` the egg to be executable: `chmod a+x [egg]` (ie, for Python 2.6, `chmod a+x setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg`)
- Run `./[egg]` (ie, for Python 2.6, `./setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg`)

Not sure if you'll need to use sudo if you're just installing it for you current user. You'd definitely need it to install it for all users.

Answer (score 5):

@main:

```
$ su
$ yum install MySQL-python
```

and it will be installed (MySQLdb).

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
from **distutils.core** import setup, Extension

if sys.version_info < (2, 3):
    raise Error("Python-2.3 or newer is required")

if os.name == "posix":
    from setup_posix import get_config
else: # assume windows
    from setup_windows import get_config

metadata, options = get_config()
metadata['ext_modules'] = [Extension(sources=['_mysql.c'], **options)]
metadata['long_description'] = metadata['long_description'].replace(r'\n', '')
setup(**metadata)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 2.7, one can easily install using this

> apt-get install python2.7-mysqldb

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can see the build dependencies in the file setup.cfg

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem right now. According to [this post](http://blog.flairpy.com/?p=19) you need to have a C Compiler or GCC. I'll try to fix the problem by installing C compiler. I'll inform you if it works (we'll I guess you don't need it anymore, but I'll post the result anyway) :)

Answer (score 1):

well installing C compiler or GCC didn't work but I found a way to successfully install mysqldb package

kindly follow Mike schrieb's (Thanks to him) instructions [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t696557-how-to-install-setuptools-egg.html) . In my case, I used setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg and setuptools-0.6c11 . Then download the executable file [here](http://www.codegood.com/archives/129) then install that file. hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

When you need to install modules in Linux/Unix and you lack sudo / admin rights, one simple way around it is to use the user scheme installation, basically run

"python setup.py install --user" from the command line in the folder of the module / library to be installed

(see http://docs.python.org/install/index.html for further details)