# Trouble Setting Up MySQLdb Module

Tags: python, mysql, macos, python-module, mysql-python

I'm pulling my hair out over here trying to set up MySQLdb on my Mac in order to connect to a remote MySQL server.

1. I have installed the latest C MySQL client libraries
2. I have installed XCode 4
3. I did naively try to install the module before installing XCode or the client libraries

I am attempting to set up the module by running the following commands in terminal:

$ sudo python setup.py build

$ sudo python setup.py install

Both of these commands fail with similar error messages.  Here is the first stack trace:

```
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_mysql.o -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pipe
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1030:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_CHARP = 4
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1044:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_LONG = 4
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1030:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_CHARP = 4
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1044:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_LONG = 4
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1151:1: warning: "WORDS_BIGENDIAN" redefined
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:1014:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
_mysql.c:2888: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1027:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_CHARP = 8
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1041:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_LONG = 8
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccU6bipK.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

And here is the stack trace for the second command:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_mysql.o -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pipe
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1030:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_CHARP = 4
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1044:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_LONG = 4
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1030:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_CHARP = 4
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1044:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_LONG = 4
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1151:1: warning: "WORDS_BIGENDIAN" redefined
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:1014:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
_mysql.c:2888: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1027:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_CHARP = 8
/usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:1041:2: warning: #warning defining SIZEOF_LONG = 8
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cchhckGP.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I have been at this for a few days now and it's starting to drive me nuts.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: WTF is up with your CFLAGS? `-arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64`? That's insanity!

Comment: Those archs are standard for the system Python 2.6 in OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've set yourself up for headaches by installing the new and forward-looking `Xcode 4` rather than the latest version of `Xcode 3` which is what Mac OS X 10.6 was released with.  The immediate issue you are running into is that Python tries to build C extension modules with the same configuration that Python itself was built.  For 10.6, that includes three architectures: `i386`, `x86_64`, and `ppc` (for compatibility with programs build on earlier systems).  Apparently `Xcode 4` has removed support for building `ppc` archs.  You *may* be able to get around this issue easily by using the `ARCHFLAGS` environment variable which is used to override the arch settings used by Python's Distutils when building extension modules.  Try doing something like this (untested as I don't have Xcode 4 handy):

```
sudo bash
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'
rm -r build
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

A better solution, as recommended elsewhere, is to not try to install MySQLdb on 10.6 by using the system Python and the MySQL binary installers.  Rather, use a complete solution by installing everything via a package manager like MacPorts.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a million.  Looks like it's time to read up on compilers...

Comment: Good luck with that!  Most of this stuff is very arcane, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Ned.  This has been a thorn in my side since I switched to OSX for dev work!  No more need for a ubuntu vm now!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that I just found to solve this. 
I encountered the same problem as you did, and my python's version is 2.7.4, and Xcode 4. Maybe you have just got the python of 32 bits, as I did. So I changed it to [2.7.5x64bit](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/python-2.7.5-macosx10.6.dmg), then there should be no problems.