# django and mysql setup in production

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I'm trying to setup mysql on my production server(Ubuntu 12.04). I followed this tutorial http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/07/how-set-django-mysql-ubuntu-hardy/ Then I run `python manage.py syncdb` It shows this error https://gist.github.com/2777611

I also checked this out [Getting "Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb" - have tried previously posted solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952187/getting-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb-have-tried-pre) Then I tried running `pip install MySQL-python` but no use, which shows this error https://gist.github.com/2777629

Could anyone tell me the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either install the python MySQL libraries included in the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

(in which case you don't need to do the `pip install MySQL-python`)

Or you can install the MySQL development libraries and then try the `pip install MySQL-python` technique:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: I believe the correct name of the package in Ubuntu 12.04 is python-mysqldb ;)

Comment: @eljunior- Good catch, thanks. I've edited my answer to reflect your correction.

Answer (score 0):

dgel has already answered but I want to add some few things just so it would be easy for beginners. At first I suggest to setup virtualenv.

Then if you are python 2.7  install

```
pip install mysql-python
```

or if you are using python 3.x

```
pip install mysqlclient
```