# Have MySQLdb installed, works outside of virtualenv but inside it doesn't exist. How to resolve?

Tags: python, virtualenv, mysql-python

I'm using the most recent versions of all software (Django, Python, virtualenv, MySQLdb) and I can't get this to work.  When I run "import MySQLdb" in the python prompt from outside of the virtualenv, it works, inside it says "ImportError: No module named MySQLdb".

I'm trying to learn Python and Linux web development.  I know that it's easiest to use SQLLite, but I want to learn how to develop larger-scale applications comparable to what I can do in .NET.  I've read every blog post on Google and every post here on StackOverflow and they all suggest that I run "sudo pip install mysql-python" but it just says "Requirement already satisfied: mysql-python in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7"

Any help would be appreciated!  I'm stuck over here and don't want to throw in the towel and just go back to doing this on Microsoft technologies because I can't even get a basic dev environment up and running.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have created the virtualenv with the `--no-site-packages` switch (the default), then system-wide installed additions such as MySQLdb are not included in the virtual environment packages.

You need to install MySQLdb with the `pip` command installed with the virtualenv. Either activate the virtualenv with the `bin/activate` script, or use `bin/pip` from within the virtualenv to install the MySQLdb library locally as well.

Alternatively, create a new virtualenv with system site-packages included by using the `--system-site-package` switch.

Comment: Another way would be to manually symlink to the system-wide ``_mysql.so``, ``_mysql_exceptions.py`` and ``MySQLdb`` (directory) from your virtualenv ``site-packages`` directory.

Comment: creating a new virtualenv with the --system-site-package works.  Is there any way to modify an existing one?

Comment: @dudemonkey: As I stated, install the package in the virtualenv with the virtualenv pip, or use codeape's suggestion and create symlinks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am getting a `mysql_config not found` error when installing from inside virtualenv

Comment: You need the MySQL development files (headers, `mysql_config` command). Make sure you have those installed. On Ubuntu and Debian those are part of the `libmysqlclient-dev` package, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I installed `libmysqlclient-dev`. But now gettin the error `Python.h: No such file or directory` while installing with `easy_install MySQL-python`

Comment: You need the same thing for Python. Ubuntu / Debian has `python2.7-dev` for Python 2.7, for example.

Comment: I have just started using ubuntu and python. Finding it difficult to set this up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters +1. Thanks! what I missed was `apt-get update`

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am coming at this from the opposite direction as the OP. Can I install a MySQL Server inside a VirtualEnv? Right now, running my code involves installing MYSQL Server on the system first, and that's a pain for users.

Answer (score 1):

1. `source $ENV_PATH/bin/activate`
2. `pip uninstall MySQL-python`
3. `pip install MySQL-python`

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I went through same problem, but using pip from virtualenv didn't solve the problem as I got this error

```
error: could not delete '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so': Permission denied
```

Earlier I had installed the package by `sudo pip install mysql-python`

To solve, copy files `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7.egg-info` and `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql*` to `~/v/lib/python-2.7/site-packages` and include `/usr/local/mysql/lib` in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable.

For the second step I am doing `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib` in `~/.profile`

Comment: Careful with `sudo` in a virtualenv -- they seem not to play very nice together.