# Error loading MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have been trying to configure django with MySQL Database.But after changing the settings file to the following

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
    'PORT': '8080',
}
```

}

when in run the `python manage.py syncdb` it shows the the following errors.Any help will be deeply appreciated.

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No mdule named 'release'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952187/getting-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb-have-tried-pre

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
easy_install MySQL-python
```

or if you have pip installed

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

If neither of those work, can you show us the entire traceback?