# django mysql connection issue

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to connect Django with a Mysql db so I change my settings.py file as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mysite',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

and when I try to run the server I get this:

![enter image description here][1]
so I fllowed the post [getting-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952187/getting-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb-have-tried-pre) and now when I do : pip install MySql=python I get this error:

```
$ pip install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MySQL-python
  Complete output from command c:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\rafa\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-sfr5rp\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read(
).replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\temp\tmpxuok6wpip-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
  C:\Users\Rafa\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program
Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\Python27\include -Ic:\Python27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\Rafa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
←[31m  Failed building wheel for MySQL-python←[0m
Failed to build MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
    Complete output from command c:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\rafa\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-sfr5rp\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(
tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\temp\pip-p1pfvy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-m
anaged --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    C:\Users\Rafa\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Progra
m Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\Python27\include -Ic:\Python27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Rafa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
←[31mCommand "c:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\rafa\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-sfr5rp\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', o
pen)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\temp\pip-p1pfvy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" f
ailed with error code 1 in c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-sfr5rp\MySQL-python←[0m
```

I appreciatte if someone can help me.

Comment: Copy and paste your error **text** into the question, not a screenshot. It's much easier to read and help that way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-inst

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Windows I would recommend installing the Mysql-python binaries (.exe), instead using pip to compile the source files, or use a wheel that matches your platform and architecture.

Check the link:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

Comment: Or probably install the python-dev to your mingwin environment.

Answer (score 0):

[install from this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5)

then type

> > python manage.py sqlmigrate {application_name} 0001
> >     python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

Root privileges

```
(env)> sudo pip install mysql-python
```

as root

```
(env)> pip install mysql-python
```