# Installing mysql-python with pip, get "Failed building wheel for mysql-python"

Tags: python, mysql

So after attempting to install mysql-python with pip, it said that "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1"

Here is my log:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Ryan> cd\
PS C:\> cd python34\flaskapp\pythonappnew
PS C:\python34\flaskapp\pythonappnew> pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysql-python ... error
  Complete output from command c:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ogoer034\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwdwnr_thpip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64 3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysql-python
  Running setup.py clean for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ogoer034\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-jx3ujzg8-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64 3.4\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ogoer034\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-jx3ujzg8-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ogoer034\mysql-python\

PS C:\python34\flaskapp\pythonappnew>
```

So from googling: I found that a few solutions that I've tried. I've uninstalled my Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable which was already installed.

I then tried to install Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 however when I open the installer it says that .NET Framework 4 is already installed. So I uninstalled it to find that its pre-included in Windows 10. So it won't let me install Microsoft C++ 2010 Compilers or whatever and I think that might be the issue I'm having? and the compilers require net framework 4.

So I found another solution saying I could change the version numbers of Framework 4 in my regedit and it would allow me to proceed with the installation of SDK 7.1. This however did not work.

So to sum up my troubleshooting process:

I tried getting SDK 7.1, it says I needed net framework 4 even though it's already included with Windows (I think this is what people were saying). So then I tried to uninstall framework from add or remove program and reinstall it. But when I go to reinstall framework 4, it says it's already installed. And when I go to SDK 7.1 it says it is uninstalled. All I want to do is install mysql-python with pip lol...

Comment: Below worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170418/django-mysql-connection-issue