# MySQL Improperly Configured Reason: unsafe use of relative path

Tags: python, mysql, django, dynamic-linking, osx-elcapitan

I'm using Django, and when I run `python manage.py runserver` I receive the following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libmysqlclient.18.dylib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so with restricted binary
```

I'm not entirely sure how to fix this. I have installed MySQL-python via pip. And I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2952187/3990714) step earlier.

I want to also point out this is with El Capitan Beta 3.

Comment: did you have any luck with fixing this? I am having the same issue

Comment: I am currently on Beta 2. Upgraded yesterday but this is still an issue.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In OS X El Capitan (10.11), Apple added [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899).

This prevents programs in protected locations like `/usr` from calling a shared library that uses a relative reference to another shared library.  In the case of `_mysql.so`, it contains a relative reference to the shared library `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`.

In the future, the shared library `_mysql.so` may be updated.  Until then, you can force it to use an absolute reference via the `install_name_tool` utility.

Assuming that `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` is in /usr/local/mysql/lib/, then run the command:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib \
  /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib \
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
```

Comment: This also let me fix an issue with the mysql2 gem in ruby. Just had to use my module instead of the _mysql.so.  Thanks.

Comment: Can the original poster up vote this answer as the correct one?

Comment: Just FYI, if you use a virtualenv, the site-packages path is inside the virtualenv folder.

Comment: Well that saved my bacon after 4 very stressful days. What bothers me is that I didn't know how to find out what I didn't know--can anyone suggest how to prep for this kind of thing in the future? I had never heard of  either install_name_tool or System Integrity Protection. What corners of the Web should I be browsing to prepare myself for things like this?

Comment: really great.It fixed my problem on my OS X system.Thank you!

Comment: @tomcam you can't know EVERYTHING :) j/k I feel you on this one. In my case I just knew that googling for "unsafe use of relative rpath libmysqlclient.18.dylib" will give me the answer. You just need to look for the exact problem in the entire error trace.

Answer (score 0):

If there are lots of relative paths to be fixed for something (as happened with me for opencv library). You can use the following snippet:

Change the ABSPATH and LIBPATHS accordingly. It will create rPathChangeCmd.txt which you can paste in the terminal. It will also create rPathChangeErr.txt in case of any errors. I would suggest check error file (if created) before pasting the commands.

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os.path

ABSPATH = "/usr/local/lib/"  # absolute path to relative libraries
# libraries to correct
LIBPATHS = ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so', '/usr/local/lib/libopencv*'] 

PREFIX = 'sudo install_name_tool -change '

assert(ABSPATH.startswith('/') and ABSPATH.endswith('/'), 
    'please provide absolute library path ending with /')

libs = []
for path in LIBPATHS:
  libs += glob.glob(path)

cmd =  []
err = []
for lib in libs:
  if not os.path.isfile(lib):
    err.append(lib+" library not found") # glob should take care
  datastr = subprocess.check_output(['otool','-l','-v', lib])
  data = datastr.split('\n') 
  for line in data:
    ll = line.split()
    if not ll: continue
    if (ll[0] == 'name' and ll[1].endswith('.dylib') and not ll[1].startswith('/')):
      libname = ll[1].split('/')[-1]
      if os.path.isfile(ABSPATH+libname):  
        cmd.append(PREFIX+ll[1]+" "+ABSPATH+libname+' '+lib)
      else:
        err.append(ABSPATH+libname+" does not exist, hence can't correct: "+ll[1]+" in: "+lib)

ohandle = open("rpathChangeCmd.txt", 'w')
for lib in cmd:
  ohandle.write(lib+'\n')
ohandle.close()

if err:
  ehandle = open("rpathChangeErr.txt", 'w')
  for e in err:
    ehandle.write(e+'\n')
  ehandle.close()
```