# Upgraded to OSX 10.11 El Capitan, now cannot use MySQL with Python/Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, pycharm, osx-elcapitan

I have a Python/Django project that I manage using PyCharm. Everything was working perfectly under Mac OSX Yosemite. This morning I upgraded to the final release version of El Capitan, now I cannot run the project. The error I get is:

> Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

I've tried all the suggestions from past questions, but none has resolved it. The most common suggestion seems to be:

> sudo pip install MySQL-python

When I do that, I get:

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MySQL-python in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

None of the other suggestions help either. I can try reinstalling MySQL, but I don't think it's the MySQL that's broken. This might have something to do with permissions. Can anyone please help get me going again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happened to me as well. I removed the package, installed mysql using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and then reinstall the package.

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
brew install mysql
pip install MySQL-python
```

If you run into any issues with brew, be sure to check their [troubleshooting page on El Capitan](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md).

Answer (score 2):

View this post : [MySQL Improperly Configured Reason: unsafe use of relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343299/mysql-improperly-configured-reason-unsafe-use-of-relative-path)

And if you have updated Xcode, open 1 time Xcode for agreement the licence.