# Rails mysql: Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, homebrew, mysql2

I had mysql and rails installed, upgraded to the latest OSX version and now I get this error when trying to run the rails-server in my dev-folder.

```
mt:project1.dev mt$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
 SUCCESS!
mt:project1.dev mt$ mysql -v
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.6.26 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Reading history-file /Users/mt/.mysql_history
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> Ctrl-C -- exit!
Writing history-file /Users/mt/.mysql_history
Aborted
mt:project1.dev mt$ rails s
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libmysqlclient.18.dylib in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle with restricted binary - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /Users/mt/Dropbox/01. fm-public/04. Dev/htdocs/project1.dev/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
mt:project1.dev mt$
```

As you can see, mysql is running and I have the lastest version installed. However, since I'm not an expert on command-line I really don't understand the error message given and what I could do now.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: I found the solution myself – disabling SIP did it for me:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-max-os-x-el

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343299/mysql-improperly-configured-reason-unsafe-use-of-relative-path