# El Capitan perl DBD unsafe use of relative path

Tags: perl, dbi, osx-elcapitan

I encountered the following error while trying to run a perl script that uses `DBI` after upgrading to El Capitan (typical!):

```
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libmysqlclient.18.dylib in /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle with restricted binary at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 194.
```

After seeing a solution posted for a similar problem in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343299/mysql-improperly-configured-reason-unsafe-use-of-relative-path) I have posted the same solution for Perl below.

Answer (score 5):

El Capitan's system integrity protection prevents programs in protected locations (in this case /usr) from calling a shared library that uses a relative reference to another shared library. The following solved it for me. Note, my mysql is installed via brew.

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also install mysql, or its open source alternative mariadb, with the "brew" tool. This avoids giving the above issue on El Capitan

```
$ brew install mysql
```

or

```
$ brew install mariadb
```

You can find brew at http://brew.sh/