# unsafe use of relative rpath libmysqlclient.18.dylib in /Users/Jh_Cend/.python-eggs/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I run my Django project, I get this error.and I tried this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343299/mysql-improperly-configured-reason-unsafe-use-of-relative-path), but it also not worked.

PS: I update OS X El Capitan few days ago.

> Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libmysqlclient.18.dylib in /Users/Jh_Cend/.python-eggs/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so with restricted binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I `pip uninstall mysqlclient` and reinstall mysqlclient.
This error was disappeared. `python manage.py runserver` will be fine.