# Install odoo8.0 on Mac OSX 10.11,I got error "unsafe use of relative rpath libpq.5.dylib"

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have downloaded Odoo 8.0 from git ，all my steps:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

Installed PostgresApp into Applications and executed

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

Installed pip

```
sudo easy_install pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

and installed homebrew and Xcode-select
Installed other libs

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool
brew install libxml2 libxslt libevent
```

Installed Python dependencies

```
    `sudo easy_install -U setuptools
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools

cd odoo/
sudo pip install --user -r requirements.txt

Successfully installed Mako-1.0.1 Pillow-2.7.0 Werkzeug-0.9.6 `
```

Running odoo

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

./odoo.py --addons-path=addons --db-filter=mydb
```

And i got this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./odoo.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "./odoo.py", line 156, in main
    import openerp
  File "/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Python_Workspace/odoo-8.0/openerp/__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    import modules
  File "/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Python_Workspace/odoo-8.0/openerp/modules/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Python_Workspace/odoo-8.0/openerp/modules/graph.py", line 32, in <module>
    import openerp.osv as osv
  File "/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Python_Workspace/odoo-8.0/openerp/osv/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import osv
  File "/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Python_Workspace/odoo-8.0/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .orm import Model, TransientModel, AbstractModel
  File "/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Python_Workspace/odoo-8.0/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..models import (
  File "/Users/Charlie/Desktop/Python_Workspace/odoo-8.0/openerp/models.py", line 56, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.6.2-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.6.2-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.6.2-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libpq.5.dylib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.6.2-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.so with restricted binary
```

I have worked on this about two days.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343299/mysql-improperly-configured-reason-unsafe-use-of-relative-path

Comment: Thanks anyway,i have fixed this issue,something about SIP,just turn it  off work for me