# python issues with MySQL in eclipse

Tags: python, mysql, eclipse, pydev, mysql-python

Example:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(passwd="passwd", db="mydb")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table""")
records = cursor.fatchone()
print records
```

provides the next error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.2.2.2011100512/pysrc/pydevd.py",
>   line 1267, in 
>       debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)  File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.2.2.2011100512/pysrc/pydevd.py",
>   line 1020, in run
>       pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script   File "/Users/user/Documents.Develop/workspace/myProject/src/Main.py",
>   line 56, in 
>       import MySQLdb   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 19, in
>      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7,
>   in    File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line
>   6, in **bootstrap** ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Users/user/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/user/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
>   Reason: image not found

Where's the error?

Comment: Maybe `records = cursor.fatchone()` should read `records = cursor.fetchone()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be here:

> Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib Referenced from:

Make sure you install the mysqldb library.
See: [How to install MySQLdb package? (ImportError: No module named setuptools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449130/how-to-install-mysqldb-package-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools)
and/or: http://www.mangoorange.com/2008/08/01/installing-python-mysqldb-122-on-mac-os-x/

You also have a syntax error in your code:

```
records = cursor.fatchone() 
--> should be
records = cursor.fetchone()
```